# How to add curl support to PHP 5 in CentOS

Tags: php, curl, centos

How to add curl support to PHP 5 in CentOS ?

After installing curl and curl-devel, what are the things that I need to do to setup curl in PHP 5

Answer (score 17):

Had the same problem. Installing php-common did the trick for me

```
yum install php-common
```

You can also specifically install the php-curl extension

```
yum install php-curl
```

Answer (score 7):

Curl support should already be built into PHP for CentOS 5 (according to http://www.centos.org/modules/newbb/viewtopic.php?topic_id=17226).

Did you restart apache after installing curl? What error messages do you get?

BTW This question seems to belong on serverfault...