# PHP Solr install not working

Tags: php, solr, centos, pecl, centos6

I've running to the error of trying to install solr with the pecl extension. I've read this one:

- [Trying to install pecl Solr extension but it needs curl](https://serverfault.com/questions/278124/trying-to-install-pecl-solr-extension-but-it-needs-curl) (Server Fault)

I'm using php 5.3.3 on a centos 6 server.

And both times I get the same problem:

```
pecl install -n solr-beta or pecl install -n solr or pear install pecl/solr

Enable Solr (yes of course) [yes] : 
Enable Solr Debugging (Compiles solr in debug mode) [no] : 
libcURL install prefix [/usr] : 
libxml2 install prefix [/usr] : 

checking for cURL in default path... not found
configure: error: Please reinstall the libcurl distribution -
    easy.h should be in <curl-dir>/include/curl/
ERROR: `/var/tmp/solr/configure --enable-solr=yes --enable-solr-debug=no --with-curl=/usr --with-libxml-dir=/usr' failed
```

Is there another fix for this?

Comment: *Another* fix? What is your fix? And have you even installed libcurl? which ssl layer is your libcurl using?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2332133/how-to-add-curl-support-to-php-5-in-centos

Comment: Curl is installed. I send my email through Postmarkapp using curl. Thats not the issue. The issue appears them using different setting? I did a work around by downloading solr-php-client from the google repo and using that. But it solve the actual problem with pecl.

Comment: Which installation guide you followed for solr? Please have a fresh installation according to https://teq.kefh.in/apache-solr-installation-and-configuration/

Answer (score 12):

i had the same problem and i just had to do is:

```
sudo apt-get install libcurl4-gnutls-dev libxml2-dev
```

And reinstall it.

Font: [link](http://phpconfigure.com/2011/04/configure-error-please-reinstall-the-libcurl-distribution/)

Comment: Additionally, on Ubuntu you might need to:
{{sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev}}

Comment: worked on Ubuntu 16.04.1 when I installed libxml2-dev as well - thanks Shehi

Answer (score 0):

The solution you have linked will only work if you actually have curl installed as a module - if you didn't do it now and try again.